# Exporting an Eclipse Project into a Runnable Jar does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, runnable

I'm trying to export my java application to a Runnable Jar file.
This worked before, but apparently I've tinkered with something and now it doesn't work.

Exporting from Eclipse works without problems, but when I'm starting the .jar an error shows up:

"Could not find the main class: game.Main. Program will exit."

Now, the game.Main class is my main class so that's ok.
When I run the .jar via command line like this:

```
java -cp D:\PathToMyJar\test.jar game.Main
```

It also works just fine.
I just can't run the .jar file itself.

The Run Configuration with which I'm exporting is set to the correct Project and main class.
I hardly used Eclipse's export features before, so I'm kinda out of options I could think of.
From what I've read it might be some problem with the manifest file, but I don't know where to check it or how to change it - apart from the fact that Eclipse should be able to do that on it's own somehow ...

PS: The manifest inside the jar file looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: game.Main
```

Main-Class is correct. I don't know what Class-Path generally is, but I guess that means wildcard, so OK too.

Comment: can you try java -jar D:\PathToMyJar\test.jar

Comment: @smp7d That starts the jar file, but it makes my graphics don't show. I guess `System.getProperty("user.dir")` doesn't work with that for some reason. That's what I'm using to get the directory of the jar file so I can grab the image files in the same directory. With the cmd line in my opening post this works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the jar contains manifest file with correctly specified main class.
Follow these instructions: http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

Comment: Well, as I said I don't even know how to check whether my jar file contains a manifest at all. I've followed the steps on "Creating a jar File in Command Prompt", however after successful compilation into a jar I get the same error again (Couldn't find main class). Apart from that it won't include all class files (the ones in sub folders are left out).

Comment: @s3rius You can type 'jar tf my.jar' or open it in winzip to see the contents.

Comment: @Robin thanks! Didn't know WinZip(rar) could read it.Well, not I got the manifest file. It reads: "Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: game.Main"So that looks OK I think. o_0